# Data science models achieving very high, unexpected accuracies?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I'm training a Gaussian Bayes classifier and for some reason I am getting perfect on everything on the classification report. Obviously this is wrong, and I was wondering why this is happening. I don't have much experience in the field, so any help is appreciated!
Kaggle Kernel Link:
https://www.kaggle.com/rafayk7/kickstarter-real

```
features_train, features_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(
    data_analyze_scaled,
    target, 
    test_size = 0.2,
    random_state=42
)

print(features_train.shape)
print(target_train.shape)
print(features_test.shape)
print(target_test.shape)
```

Gives

```
(265337, 254)
(265337,)
(66335, 254)
(66335,)
```

And then when I train it,

```
model = GaussianNB()

pred = model.fit(features_train, target_train).predict(features_test)

accuracy = classification_report(pred, target_test)
print(accuracy)
```

This gives me 1.0 on everything (precicision, recall, accuracy f1)
Even a logistic regression model is giving me 100% accuracy. I don't think this is overfitting because it is a flat 100%. 
any help is appreciated!

Here is a snapshot of the data:
[image]

```
target = data_analyze_scaled['state']
data_analyze_scaled.drop('state', axis=1)
```

This is my target and data_analyze_scaled that I use in my train_test_split

Comment: Check for data leakage between your labels and your features. What is your target, and can any of the features by themselves be used to directly calculate the target variable?

Comment: My target is the state variable, it is a binary success/fail and so I don't think it can be calculated.

Comment: @G.Anderson would it be a good idea to ensure that the target variable is well distributed in the training set? What ratio is generally acceptable for classification problems?

Comment: The first thing I would recommend is to read about data leakage, what it is, and try to apply it critically to your model. At a quick glance through the kaggle page, let me ask you a question. Do you think you could use the pledged amount compared to the goal amount to predict the success of the campaign?

Comment: @G.Anderson I have a question about data leakage. I removed the pledged features from my model, and got a lower accuracy that was still higher than most others. Then, I removed backers, and got an even lower frequency but still higher than what other people got. Now I'm thinking, when should I stop removing features that I think may be affecting the result if I suspect that it's higher than it should be?

Comment: One option is to go the other direction. Try to predict the dependent variable with each feature individually, or with pairs of related features. If one feature, or two features, can predict with near 100% accuracy, think how they relate to the target. Additionally, you can use things like `df.corr()` or correlation heatmaps to see which features are correlated with the target near `1.0` or `-1.0`

Comment: And one possibly more important consideration: Which of your features would you _not_ know before the end of the kickstarter campaign? If you're trying to predict success before the campaign ends, then you wouldn;t know the total backers, or the total pledged, or any statistic post-close

Comment: Thanks! Giving me a more holistic view on these problems, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in `data_analyze_scaled.drop('state', axis=1)`.
This statement will remove the column `state` from the data frame and returns the modified data frame which has to be saved in another data frame object like:

`data_analyze_scaled_x = data_analyze_scaled.drop('state', axis=1)`

And now you should use this in your train test split.

In your existing implementation you have given the target variable as a feature to your model. So the accuracy is going to be 1 which ever model you use.

Comment: There's the data leakage, nice catch. Also worth noting that, rather than assigning it, OP can also include the parameter `inplace=True` to the drop operation if they don't want to keep the original dataframe in memory